docker rootless aspnet SDK not found
I can't get my application created with a dockerfile to work in rootless.
I saw that I had to add USER app but the problem is still there.
Here is my docker file :
# build .NET app:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore
# Build and publish a release
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

USER app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]

Here is the error I see in docker logs.
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:

You intended to execute a .NET application:
The application 'Intranet.dll' does not exist.
You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
In root mode the docker works fine.

Are you actually getting an exception when building this image or running the container? Can you add the logs/error stack here?

Your error message doesn't match your Dockerfile. In your Dockerfile, you try to run app.dll but the error message says that it can't find Intranet.dll. Make sure you've built the image after making changes and that the DLL name matches your project name.

Yes it's a problem with dll name
thanks
